# Get Funding Rate Data From CoinGlass in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, api

I am trying to get API data from CoinGlass and I have this working code:

```
# https://coinglass.github.io/API-Reference/#general-info
# 16 Nov 2022

# Symbol:
# BTC,ETH,EOS,BCH,LTC,XRP,BSV,ETC,TRX,LINK are now supported

# Exchange Name:
# Bitmex,Binance,Bybit,Okex,Huobi,FTX,Deribit,Kraken,Bitfinex,Phemex are now supported


# Parameter Default  Description
# type      string  default C (Token Margined=C, USDT or USD Margined=U)
# symbol    string  Symbol

url = "https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=BTC&type=C"
params = {}
headers = {'coinglassSecret': '1be40c5d2d71425084cd08b9e9817557'}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = params)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

I am going to add more symbols to the url. I made a list of possible symbols but it did not return anything.

```
symbol_list = ['BTC', 'ETH']

# Parameter Default  Description
# type      string  default C (Token Margined=C, USDT or USD Margined=U)
# symbol    string  Symbol

url = "https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol=symbol_list&type=C"
params = {}
headers = {'coinglassSecret': '1be40c5d2d71425084cd08b9e9817557'}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = params)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: There is hard-coded _symbol_ in your former example. Try *hard-coded* multipath symbol in the latter one…

Comment: @JosefZ Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop over your `symbol_list` with a `for` loop:

```
import requests

symbol_list = ['BTC', 'ETH']
headers = {'coinglassSecret': '1be40c5d2d71425084cd08b9e9817557'}
params = {}
responses = []
for symbol in symbol_list:
    url = f"https://open-api.coinglass.com/api/pro/v1/futures/funding_rates_chart?symbol={symbol}&type=C"
    print(symbol)
    response = responses.append(requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, data = params))
```

Now you have a `responses` array which contains your wanted info for both symbols.

Hope this helps!